# Two space line break doesnt work on GitHub when converting .rmd to .md using github_document

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I was trying to convert an `.rmd` document to `.md` to upload on GitHub using `output: github_document` in my YAML header.

Apparently, the conversion does not respect the two or more spaces I used in my .rmd file to force a linebreak.

**Example:** I created this little `.rmd` file:

```
---
title: "Line Break issue"
output: github_document
---

1.  My First point  
Another point right below  
and more

1.  My second point
```

I used two spaces to force a break between "My first Point" and "Another point..." and "and more". When I knit, the preview is fine, however, when I upload to GitHub the linebreaks are only adequately respected in the `.rmd` file as you can see [here](https://github.com/M-E-Steiner/MyDesk/blob/master/line_break_question.rmd) but apparently gone in the `.md` file as you can [here](https://github.com/M-E-Steiner/MyDesk/blob/master/line_break_question.md).

Why is that?

EDIT:

I am using `rmarkdown_0.9.6` within RStudio `Version 0.99.1130` on `R 3.3.0`.

Comment: Looking at [the raw markdown file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/M-E-Steiner/MyDesk/master/line_break_question.md), there are no trailing spaces, so it's not a problem with Github's renderer - it's something in the conversion process.  What are you actually using to convert this file?

Comment: Its within RStudio so the converter is pandoc. I noticed the missing trailing spaces too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if the behavior of GitHub's markdown renderer has changed. Formerly GitHub Flavored Markdown automatically created an HTML line break for any line break within Markdown (even those without 2 trailing spaces). As a result the pandoc conversion to github_markdown stripped off the 2 trailing spaces (as they were not necessary or meaningful in github_markdown).

Posting some test files on GitHub today however it looks like they now *require* the two spaces to yield a line break. I don't know if this change is permanent or temporary (as it will be sure to break a bunch of existing code). To deal with this I've added a `hard_line_breaks` option to `github_document`:

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/0cbfcf7ebde5f587e70a064ae7c484cfd849ba6a

With this change the YAML of your example would need to look like this to preserve the two-spaces:

```
---
title: "Line Break issue"
output: 
  github_document:
    hard_line_breaks: false
---
```

If this appears to be a permanent change by GitHub then I'll change the default to `true` so `github_document` will produce the right markdown by default.